# How to put marks in a scrollbar

Tags: javafx, scrollbar, javafx-8

I'm implementing a search feature and I would like to highlight the positions of the matches in the scrollbar of my table view.

Is there any way to show color marks in a scrollbar in JavaFX?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do e.g. what Eclipse does? I.e. have a vertical bar to the right of the scrollbar where you put marks/highlights (errors/warnings in Eclipse).

Comment: @Jonathan It could be an option indeed. I've been using using intellij for some time now and I had forgotten the eclipse way. Too bad I can't find any built-in way to show them directly in the scrollbar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you get access to the `ScrollBar` after it has been layouted for the first time, you can add the marks to the track:

```
public class ScrollBarMark {

    private final Rectangle rect;
    private final DoubleProperty position = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public ScrollBarMark() {
        rect = new Rectangle(5, 5, Color.RED.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5));
        rect.setManaged(false);
    }

    public void attach(ScrollBar scrollBar) {
        StackPane sp = (StackPane) scrollBar.lookup(".track");
        rect.widthProperty().bind(sp.widthProperty());
        sp.getChildren().add(rect);
        rect.layoutYProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> {
            double height = sp.getLayoutBounds().getHeight();
            double visibleAmout = scrollBar.getVisibleAmount();
            double max = scrollBar.getMax();
            double min = scrollBar.getMin();
            double pos = position.get();
            double delta = max - min;

            height *= 1 - visibleAmout / delta;

            return height * (pos - min) / delta;
        },
                position,
                sp.layoutBoundsProperty(),
                scrollBar.visibleAmountProperty(),
                scrollBar.minProperty(),
                scrollBar.maxProperty()));
    }

    public final double getPosition() {
        return this.position.get();
    }

    public final void setPosition(double value) {
        this.position.set(value);
    }

    public final DoubleProperty positionProperty() {
        return this.position;
    }

    public void detach() {
        StackPane parent = (StackPane) rect.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.getChildren().remove(rect);
            rect.layoutYProperty().unbind();
            rect.widthProperty().unbind();
        }
    }

}
```

Right now this only works with vertical `ScrollBar`s.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ScrollBar scrollBar = new ScrollBar();
    scrollBar.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

    scrollBar.setMax(100);
    scrollBar.setVisibleAmount(50);
    scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((a,b,c) -> System.out.println(c));

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(scrollBar);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 200, 500);

    // do layout
    root.applyCss();
    root.layout();

    ScrollBarMark mark1 = new ScrollBarMark();
    ScrollBarMark mark2 = new ScrollBarMark();
    mark1.attach(scrollBar);
    mark2.attach(scrollBar);
    mark1.setPosition(50);
    mark2.setPosition(75);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Wow, this looks excellent. I can't test it right now, but I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: I did a couple tests, and this is precisely what I was looking for. I added thickness and color properties, and I'll update a bit the class to fit any scrollbar orientation and orientation change.

Comment: Btw, why `height *= 1 - visibleAmout / delta` ?

Comment: @Joffrey You cannot move the top of the thumb along the full length of a `ScrollBar`, since the bottom of the thumb cannot be moved below the bottom of the track. Therefore you need to take that part out of the overall heigth available as positions for the top of the thumb.

Comment: It doesn't work this way with marks. Imagine your overflow is only a few lines. You have a thumb taking about 90% of the scrollbar. I don't want the marks constrained in the remaining 10%. Moreover, the thumb is supposed to represent the visible part of the scrollbar. If some of the marks are in the view port, they should be under the thumb, it is perfectly legitimate.